# Specifying return rows in LINQ2DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

I have a requirement to extract a distinct subset of rows from a DataTable, and thought LINQ2DataSets may be a useful and clean way to do this, however it appears that it is not possible to simply identify return rows from a LINQ2DS query as follows

```
var result = from r in fips.AsEnumerable() select
r.Field<string>("FACILITY_PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_CODE"),
r.Field<string>("PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_NAME"),
r.Field<string>("...
```

as I start getting errors after the first comma.

Is this a correct assumption, and how would I get around it to return a subset of columns from the dataset that I can apply a Distinct() method to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the new statement and field names:

```
var result = from r 
    in fips.AsEnumerable() 
    select new
    {
        FacProcess = r.Field<string>("FACILITY_PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_CODE"),
        GroupName = r.Field<string>("PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_NAME"),
        Item3 = r.Field<string>("Item3")
    };
```

You can also explicitly declare that you are going to use a type:

```
var result = from r 
    in fips.AsEnumerable() 
    select new MyType("InitClassParams") 
    {
        FacProcess = r.Field<string>("FACILITY_PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_CODE"),
        GroupName = r.Field<string>("PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_NAME"),
        Item3 = r.Field<string>("Item3")
    };
```

[Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) (VP Developer Devision, Microsoft) has some good info about LINQ (he talks about LINQ to SQL, but most of it applies regardless).

Then apply the distinct clause:

```
var result = from r 
    in fips.AsEnumerable() 
    select new
    {
        FacProcess = r.Field<string>("FACILITY_PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_CODE"),
        GroupName = r.Field<string>("PROCESS_SUB_GROUP_NAME"),
        Item3 = r.Field<string>("Item3")
    }
    distinct;
```

Then put it to a list or iterate over it. Nothing will be selected/distincted/etc until something like on of the following is run:

```
var list = result.ToList()
foreach(var item in result) {}
```